# Dropdownlist resetting and not keeping value during postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, dropdown

I know this is a quite common problem but I couldn't find a solution over internet yet. Maybe I got into a tunnel vision, I don't know.

I have a gridview and the dropdownlist related to it keeps resetting. It's been hours and I'm still having this problem.

The table which has the DropDownList

```
<table class="filtertable" EnableViewState="true">
        <tr align="center">
            <td width="100%">
                <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="Yeni Kayıt" OnClick="btnNew_OnClick"
                    CssClass="btn" Visible="true" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnArama" runat="server" Text="Gümrük Arama" OnClick="btnArama_Click"
                    CssClass="btn" Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="trGumrukArama">
            <td>
                <fieldset style="margin-top: 5px">
                    <legend>Ülke Gümrük Arama</legend>
                    <table EnableViewState="true">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUlke">Ülke:&nbsp</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpUlke" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="true"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpUlke_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGumrukKodu"> Gümrük Kodu: &nbsp</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGumrukKodu"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGumrukAdi">Gümrük Adı: &nbsp</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGumrukAdi"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="btnSearch" Text="Ara" OnClick="btnSearch_OnClick" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            drpUlke_Bind();
            BindList();
            //drpUlke.SelectedValue = ViewState["ListUlkeKod"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void drpUlke_Bind()
    {
        DataTable dt = CacheManager.UlkelerGercek.Tables[0];
        DataTable dtNew = CacheManager.UlkelerGercek.Tables[0].Clone();

        DataRow drseperator = dtNew.NewRow();
        drseperator["id"] = -1;
        drseperator["harfKod"] = "";
        drseperator["adi"] = "------------------------------------";
        dtNew.Rows.Add(drseperator);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtNew.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            dr["adi"] = dr["harfKod"] + " - " + dr["adi"];
            if (dr["harfKod"].ToString().Trim() == "TR")
                dtNew.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            else
                dtNew.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        drpUlke.DataSource = dtNew;
        drpUlke.DataValueField = "harfKod";
        drpUlke.DataTextField = "adi";
        drpUlke.DataBind();

        drpKaydetUlke.DataSource = dtNew;
        drpKaydetUlke.DataValueField = "harfKod";
        drpKaydetUlke.DataTextField = "adi";
        drpKaydetUlke.DataBind();
    }

    protected void drpUlke_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

.
.
.
.
.

private void BindList()
    {
        int TotalCount;
        int Start = (CurrentPageIndex - 1) * _pageRowCount;

        string UlkeKodu = drpUlke.SelectedValue;
        //ViewState["ListUlkeKod"] = UlkeKodu;
        string GumrukKodu = txtGumrukKodu.Text;
        string GumrukAdi = txtGumrukAdi.Text;
        //drpUlke.SelectedValue = ViewState["ListUlkeKod"].ToString();

        DataSet ds = (Stored Procedure Here)
        gvUlkeGumruk.DataSource = ds;
        gvUlkeGumruk.DataBind();

        int intTotalCount;
        int intCurrentCount;

        intTotalCount = TotalCount == -1 ? 0 : TotalCount;
        intCurrentCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1;

        pcBottom.TotalRowCount = intTotalCount;
        pcBottom.PageRowCount = _pageRowCount;
        pcBottom.CurrentRowCount = intCurrentCount;

        pcBottom.BindPaging();

        pcBottom.Visible = intTotalCount > 0;
    }
```

Just the related parts, If I'm missing something please let me know.

I tried using viewstate variables but they kept getting resetted too.

edit:

I came across a few posts on internet about this problem. They were saying as a solution that their dropdown lists value field not being unique. I checked the value field and it's values are all unique.

Comment: post your `drpUlke_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: It is an empty method atm, I experimented with it before but it didn't solve the problem too. Tried adding a variable inside it to hold the selected value via a viewstate variable, didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

When you want the DDL data to survive a postback you've got to reload the DDL during the postback lifecycle. You can do this manually, or enable ViewState which you'd have to do on the control chain.

If you go the manual route of loading data in control/page init (regardless of the IsPostBack flag) you can improve performance by making sure your data is cached. You'll be skipping the ViewState (good for client performance), but hitting your DB more. If that's a problem then you can go back to using ViewState.

Comment: Are we sure that the page directive, or control directive, has it set?

Answer (score 1):

This may happens because of `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`. Removed that property and try again

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are true on their own cases and not to be dismissed as incorrect. Due to the nature of my problem, I can't designate one as answer.

I ended up sending drop down choice as a request parameter to each other page. We are using a custom pagination mechanism and that is the reason I had to end up this way.